How can I avoid "ConnectionShutdown('CRC mismatch on header')"?
I'm using Datastax's python driver to submit concurrent requests like so:
concurrent.execute_concurrent(...concurrency=50)

The total number of requests submitted is around 200, and some result sets have thousands of rows.
I occasionally run into the following error:
exception while fetching results ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {\
  <Host: 127.0.0.1:9043 us-east>: ConnectionShutdown('CRC mismatch on header fc3b22. Received 85", computed 67cd61.'), \
  <Host: 10.0.0.235:9042 us-east>: ConnectionException('Host has been marked down or removed')})

How can I avoid this error? I suspect it's occurring due to the large amount of data being transferred over the network but can't pinpoint the exact root cause. What is a safe level of concurrency?

driver version: 3.29.1

cassandra version: cqlsh 6.1.0 | Cassandra 4.1.4 | CQL spec 3.4.6 | Native protocol v5]

I tried playing around with different levels of concurrency - I need to set it at least 50 otherwise the queries take way too long to finish executing.

nodetool status shows that all the nodes are up

optimized my queries so that exact partition key is specified in each query - none of them use the "IN" operator on partitions.

used prepared statements



I had the same issue during performance tests, under Cassandra 5.0.0 in case that I used ProtocolVersion.V5. I solved the issue, when I used older protocol version (ProtocolVersion.V4). You can see part of the code:
...
self._cluster = Cluster(contact_points = self._run_setup['ip'],
                        port = self._run_setup['port'],
                        auth_provider = auth_provider,
                        load_balancing_policy = load_balancing_policy,
                        control_connection_timeout = Setting.TIMEOUT,
                        idle_heartbeat_interval = Setting.TIMEOUT,
                        connect_timeout = Setting.TIMEOUT,
                        protocol_version = ProtocolVersion.V4)
                        # issue with 'CRC mismatch on header ...', not use protocol V5
                        # protocol_version = ProtocolVersion.V5)
...

It seems that ProtocolVersion.V5 is little buggy.

It seems to me like you actually have 2 different issues.
The first one is that you have a node configured to listen for client connections on localhost:
... <Host: 127.0.0.1:9043 us-east>: ConnectionShutdown('CRC mismatch on header fc3b22. Received 85", computed 67cd61.') ...

Unless your application is hosted on the same server as the Cassandra node, you should never bind the CQL port to localhost. Instead, you should configure the node to listen for connections on an IP address that is routable from the application.
For the second issue indicated by:
... <Host: 10.0.0.235:9042 us-east>: ConnectionException('Host has been marked down or removed') ...

The client is unable to connect to the host because it has been "marked down". The driver's ConvictionPolicy decides when nodes should be marked as "down" because of failures.
The most common reason for a node to be marked as "down" is when it is unresponsive or unavailable, usually because it is overloaded and no longer responding to new requests. In your case, node 10.0.0.235 is probably taking all the traffic and therefore unresponsive because the other node is not reachable.
Check the configuration of the other node and make sure it is accepting requests from clients. Cheers!

Thank you. I've set up an ssh tunnel to listen to remote cassandra locally, hence using localhost. Secondly, the nodes in my cluster don't seem to be overloaded. I have datadog set up to monitor the cpu load and latencies on the cluster, and it's normal. Per the docs, https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.11/com/datastax/driver/core/exceptions/CrcMismatchException.html, this kind of exception doesn't have anything to do with the server at all.

Relevant jira: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-1337

The CRC mismatch is unrelated to the the other node being marked down.
